# Trying to Understand Dependency Properties

Tags: .net, dependency-properties

I have been trying to understand and get something working with dependency properties.

I have read loads of descriptions and explanations about DP's, and I also think I understand where they should be used.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568646/dependency-properties) and the links / references contain therein.

However, im still having problems. These maybe just mental blockages, maybe im clinging onto some idea or belief that i cant let go of.. anyway..

What im trying to do is create a control with a DP on it.
Use that control in xaml and bind to the DP.

When i specify a value for the DP in the xaml the value is diaplayed on the user control as expected.

```
<DpTestProj:UserControl1 MyName="Steve"
```

However when i try to bind to it the value is not set, and i get

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PersonName' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl1' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PersonName; DataItem='UserControl1' (Name=''); target element is 'UserControl1' (Name=''); target property is 'MyName' (type 'String')

Which suggests i have done something wrong with the binding or datacontext somewhere.
But i cant see what.

My code is as follows.

UserControl1 has the following DP

```
public const string MyNamePropertyName = "MyName";
public string MyName
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(MyNameProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MyNameProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    MyNamePropertyName,
    typeof(string),
    typeof(UserControl1),
    new UIPropertyMetadata("No Name"));
```

Its used on the MainWindow like this

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DpTestProj:UserControl1 MyName="{Binding PersonName}" MyList="{Binding SomeListItems}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I'm using MVVM Light si the data context of the MainWindow is

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

PersonName is a normal CLR (string) property that lives on the MainViewModel

If its easier I have posted the entire solution [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B3ZKsZZ9ODWrNDEzOTUwNGMtZDIxNS00ODE5LWE3ZmUtZTA2YmYwYTM2NjMy&sort=name&layout=list&num=50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is...

you cant bind to the clr wrapper of a dp directly with a vanilla binding (even if you have set the dataContext of the userControl as this (i.e. the code behind of the userControl))

You can do one of two things to get changes to the dependency property reflected in the UI elements.

1)  Use a RelativeSource Binding in FindAncestor mode

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DpWrapperProp}"
```

2) Use the Dp's callback to update your UI element. (If youre using the callback to do some validation anyway, then this might be the route for you).
Because the Callback is *Static* you need to create a non static method to do the update, and call that from the static method. The ui element (label textBlock whatever) also need to be named.

```
    private static void ChangeText(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as MyUserControl).UpdateText(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }

    private void UpdateText(string newText)
    {
        MyLabel.Content = newText; //set the content of the named label 
                                   //defined in the userControl XAML
    }
```

*the above examples are generic and not nesecarily related to my original code.

fyi i arrived at these solutons with the help of [this](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/usercontrols_dependency_properties_pg5.htm) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d6583372-349c-449f-bb61-ccc3e08fb6f2?prof=required)

Answer (score 0):

Your DependencyProperty isn't the issue here; the issue is the data you're binding it *to*.  The binding isn't finding a property called Main.PersonName from whatever the `Locator` resource is.

Comment: No and thats whats confusing. I tried <Label Text="{Binding PersonName} /> and this works.  So i know the binding, datacontext and paths etc are okay (for normal binding at least). Is there something special needed for this. (I cant believe there is)

Comment: Well, if `{Binding PersonName}` works in a label, it'll work in the usercontrol too.  If you put an `OnPropertyChanged` callback on your dependency property, is it being hit?  And/or: are there any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <DpTestProj:UserControl1 MyName="{Binding PersonName}"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonName}" Background="SkyBlue"/>
    </StackPanel>

Comment: that was meant to be: Well yes. it should. doing this.    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <DpTestProj:UserControl1 MyName="{Binding PersonName}"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonName}" Background="SkyBlue"/>
    </StackPanel>.. gets me the binding expression error.  System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PersonName' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl1' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PersonName; DataItem='UserControl1' (Name=''); target element is 'UserControl1' (Name=''); target property is 'MyName' (type 'String')

Comment: Are you overriding the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`?  Say, in the constructor of the `UserControl`?

Comment: yes, i have it set to 'this' on the constructor on the usercontrol. without that it would be bound directly to the main window. and since the DP im using is defined on the usercontrol, i thought it appropriate to bind to the usercontrol its self.

Comment: Well, that's your problem: you're trying to bind to the property `PersonName` on your UserControl, not on your window, because you're overriding the data context.  My personal suggestion is *never* to forecefully override the datacontext on a usercontrol for that exact reason - there are cleaner ways of doing this in markup that don't break the use of your control.

Comment: okay. i think i did it this way because i was looking for a reason to use a dependency property. if i bind directly, without going through the DP, then i wont need the DP.

Answer (score -1):

```
<DpTestProj:UserControl1 MyName="{Binding MyName}" ... />
```

?

**Update:**

Ok I took a closer look at your solution. In your `UserControl1` you're basically overwriting your original DataContext.

To make things work, just remove that line:

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this; // this makes you lose your MainViewModel
    }
```

And edit your `UserControl1.xaml` accordingly to bind to your original `MainViewModel`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding PersonName}"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeListItems}" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"/>
```

Now I don't know your original scenario of why you wanted to set your `UserControl1`'s view model to itself. That's a very unusual way of doing things that is not very MVVM-like. If you really want to go that route, you'd have to create a new ViewModel that stores the original `MainViewModel` in one property and the `UserControl1` in another.

Comment: Well, that removes the binding error but what your'e doing is binding the DP to its self. So the default value is displayed in the usercontrol

Comment: okay, yes that gets the value from the mainViewModel into the control on UserControl1. But it negates the need for the Dependency Property. Basically i was trying to do something with a DP thats all.

Comment: @Cha0sEngine I'd say in use cases like this (binding to domain model data, auto-passing the datacontext through the control hierarchy) you don't need to deal with Dependency Properties. They are part of the WPF/Silverlight infrastructure to make certain UI concepts work. Dependency Properties become interesting and necessary when implementing your own general controls or framework elements. In such cases you won't work with view models in contrast then.

Comment: @herzmeister der welten as i said, i was experimenting with dependency properties. this was meant to be an extremely simple user control. If we forget about my MainWindow (test harness) for now, how would you implement my "control"? would you use DP's to enable binding? would you use MVVM on the user control? or is it not possible to do so? thanks.

Comment: Maybe we'd need a more meaningful example, otherwise it's a bit difficult to clarify things in a better way. Yes, the guideline is to use DPs on your own controls and user controls to make them bindable, whereas you'd use MVVM (INotifyPropertyChanged) on your view models. So are you trying to implement a `PersonInfoControl` on which you can set the name and some list from outside declaratively? I now *believe* what you are *really* looking for here is TemplateBinding (or Relative Source TemplatedParent binding): http://www.google.com/search?q=templatebinding+relativesource

Comment: I will investigate using a lookless control and have a template.  However I did some more research and found that this <local:MyControl Margin="5" TextContent="{Binding ElementName=aHiddenLabel, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />  i.e. using ElementName binding works. Normal binding still dosent work though.

Comment: Sorry.. The above code is from a different solution, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Yes, using WPF's binding engine against other framework elements, be it by `ElementName`, `TemplateBinding`s or whatever, is the correct approach for your scenario. "Normal" binding with the `DataContext` would of course work too if you create appropriate view models that store both data and controls, but that would make things much more complicated and, as said, is unusual and not what MVVM is intended for.

Comment: I think I have the answer, but before i post it as the answer I thought id see what you think... It seems that the problem is when i try to use binding on the userControl, so from my original example I was binding to MyName in the usercontrol, my name is defined on the usercontrols code behind and is the wrapper for the DP. When I use the DP callback to update the UI element, it works as expected.